# Algorithm to find minimum edge weights on planar graph in unit plane

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Suppose I have planar graph with a fixed number of vertices and edges. Each vertex must be located at a unique integral point on the unit plane ( $(0,0), (1,1), (1,0)$, etc), and each edge must be a straight line segment. Any number of vertices can be moved, rotated, flipped, etc as long as the graph remains planar (no intersections after movement).

Example below.

Here is a graph of six vertices, and given edges. The top image is arranged with total edge length ~ $10.656$. However, this can be improved by rearranging the vertices as in the second image. This reduces the total edge length to ~ $10.242$. (I don't know if this is minimal)

Is there an algorithm to find the minimum total edge length in such graphs? (Or an algorithm for a more restricted problem statement, e.g. only up to 4-connected vertices?)

[image]

Comment: An initial thought, a region with four sides is optimal as a square, a region with three sides is optimal as a right angle triangle. There should be one or more optimal arrangements for more edges. This fact can be used to describe a greedy algorithm, which I would assume is not optimal.

Comment: Must all edges be straight? Curved edges usually don't help, but there are some edge cases (hah) where they're useful. For example, to embed $K_4$, we can put points at $\{(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (2,0)\}$ with a curved edge from $(0,0)$ to $(2,0)$ of length $2+\epsilon$, which is better than any solution with straight edges.

Comment: The edges should be straight